# Does RubyMine/LSP ignore YARD @private @!visibility private settings?

Tags: ruby, rubymine, yard, language-server-protocol

What I'm trying to achieve:

I have a public method in a class that I would like to be removed from autocompletion in IDEs by making it private via YARD.

I've tried adding `@api private`, `@!visibility private`, `@private` and it doesn't seem to make any difference - IDE in documentation popups clearly shows this method is still public, and it is still available to be auto-completed.

Why not just make this method a true `private` one?
I'm trying to achieve full backward compatibility for existing users. It's a public gem.

The goal is better UX for end users by removing unnecessary methods from being listed in auto-completion.

IDEs affected: RubyMine(2021.1), Emacs/LSP(Solagraph backend).. probably Visual Studio Code as well.

So, the question is "Does RubyMine/LSP ignore YARD @private @!visibility private settings?" or is it something with my local setup?

Comment: I don't see a question in here, just a statement of fact. What is your actual, concrete programming question? And what answer do you expect other than "looks like RubyMine doesn't support it, go file an enhancement request?"

Comment: The question has just been clarified

Comment: At the moment, these tags aren't supported in RubyMine so could you please submit your request directly on the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY